# Call Webservice from a Oracle Trigger

Tags: web-services, plsql

I'm trying to call a web service from a trigger on a data insert.

Below is the trigger written making the service call.

```
create or replace trigger TRG_EDI_TRANSACTIONS
  before insert on edi_transactions
  for each row
declare
  --SOAP REQUESTS/RESPONSE
  soap_req_msg VARCHAR2(2000);

  -- HTTP REQUEST/RESPONSE
  http_req  UTL_HTTP.req;
  http_resp UTL_HTTP.resp;
  buffer    varchar2(4000);
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
begin

  soap_req_msg := '
               <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:edi="http://edi.hnb.com" xmlns:xsd="http://edi.hnb.com/xsd">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <edi:processEDIData>
         <edi:request>
     <xsd:bankCode>' || :NEW.Bank_Code ||
                  '</xsd:bankCode>
            <xsd:brCode>' || :NEW.Br_Code ||
                  '</xsd:brCode>
            <xsd:cardParticular>' || :NEW.Tran_Particular ||
                  '</xsd:cardParticular>
            <xsd:crncyCode>' || :NEW.Crncy_Code ||
                  '</xsd:crncyCode>
            <xsd:dateStatus>' || :NEW.Date_Status ||
                  '</xsd:dateStatus>
            <xsd:dthInitSolId>' || :NEW.Dth_Init_Sol_Id ||
                  '</xsd:dthInitSolId>
            <xsd:foracid>' || :NEW.Foracid ||
                  '</xsd:foracid>
            <xsd:partTranSrlNum>' ||
                  :NEW.Part_Tran_Srl_Num || '</xsd:partTranSrlNum>
            <xsd:partTranType>' || :NEW.Part_Tran_Type ||
                  '</xsd:partTranType>
            <xsd:pstdDate>' || :NEW.Pstd_Date ||
                  '</xsd:pstdDate>
            <xsd:retry>' || :NEW.Retry ||
                  '</xsd:retry>
            <xsd:solId>' || :NEW.Sol_Id ||
                  '</xsd:solId>
            <xsd:tranAmt>' || :NEW.Tran_Amt ||
                  '</xsd:tranAmt>
            <xsd:tranCrncyCode>' || :NEW.Tran_Crncy_Code ||
                  '</xsd:tranCrncyCode>
            <xsd:tranDate>' || :NEW.Tran_Date ||
                  '</xsd:tranDate>
            <xsd:tranId>' || :NEW.Tran_Id ||
                  '</xsd:tranId>
            <xsd:tranParticular>' || :NEW.Tran_Particular ||
                  '</xsd:tranParticular>
            <xsd:tranRmks>' || :NEW.Tran_Rmks ||
                  '</xsd:tranRmks>
            <xsd:tranSubType>' || :NEW.Tran_Sub_Type ||
                  '</xsd:tranSubType>
            <xsd:tranType>' || :NEW.Tran_Type ||
                  '</xsd:tranType>
            <xsd:trfStatus>' || :NEW.Trf_Status || '</xsd:trfStatus>
         </edi:request>
      </edi:processEDIData>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
  ';

  http_req := UTL_HTTP.begin_request('http://10.110.6.49:8305/services/prxy_edi_router_svc ',
                                     'POST',
                                     'HTTP/1.1');
  UTL_HTTP.set_header(http_req, 'Accept-Encoding', 'gzip,deflate');
  UTL_HTTP.set_header(http_req, 'Content-Type', 'text/xml');
  utl_http.set_header(http_req, 'SOAPAction', 'processEDIData');
  UTL_HTTP.set_header(http_req, 'Content-Length', length(soap_req_msg));
  UTL_HTTP.set_header(http_req, 'Host', '10.110.6.49:8305');
  UTL_HTTP.set_header(http_req, 'Connection', 'Keep-Alive');
  UTL_HTTP.write_text(http_req, soap_req_msg);

  http_resp := UTL_HTTP.get_response(http_req);

  begin
    loop
      utl_http.read_line(http_resp, buffer);
      dbms_output.put_line(buffer);
    end loop;
    utl_http.end_response(http_resp);
  exception
    when utl_http.end_of_body then
      utl_http.end_response(http_resp);
  end;

end TRG_EDI_TRANSACTIONS;
```

Is there a way not to wait for the response.

(A similar one to "OUT_ONLY" property in WSO2 ESB, which sends the request out
and doesn't expect a response)

Problem is when I call the web service via trigger, and if the web service is down, a connection timeout occurs, trigger is waiting for the response and error an error is being thrown.

Will be please if anyone could guide on this.

Oracle version 11.2.0.3.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dbms_job.submit`. This package schedules and manages jobs in the job queue.

```
  dbms_job.submit(job => my_job, 
    what => 'my_procedure(foo);'
    next_date => sysdate+1,
    interval => 'sysdate+1');
```

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_job.htm#BABHCBFD).

Comment: Hi @mkuligowski, Thanks for the quick response, did the reading, it seems in the my_procedure also might need to wait for the response, I'm trying to eliminate that, and this seems to be like a queue mechanism.

Comment: @Yasothar your trigger won't wait for the job. The job will be only scheduled and _my_procedure_ will be executed in appropriate time. Of course, _my_procedure_ have to wait for the web service response, but your trigger will not.

Comment: @Yasothar and mkuligowski do you have an example for calling a REST webservice from Oracle Trigger ? My requirement is for every CRUD operation on specific table, specific column(String) I should call a REST webservice.