# How can i capture data change of one table in oracle and post changed information to one web service intermediately

Tags: oracle, web-services, apache-kafka, oracle-cdc

I have an account table in oracle, in this table has balance column, how can i capture a change of this column and post new value to one endpoint ws intermediately
Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You've tagged this with Apache Kafka, can you edit your question to clarify if this is how you are going to implement it and need a Kafka-based answer? Or the solution doesn't need to include it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing this with an AFTER UPDATE TRIGGER?
Oracle has a UTL_HTTP package which you can use within the trigger to make a webservice call.

The code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50246053/call-webservice-from-a-oracle-trigger/50246147) can be a good starting point